# How can I give the recyclerview dynamically constraint?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, admob, android-constraintlayout

I have layout with a recyclerview and adView. If the ad loads, it looks fine, but if it doesn't, there's a huge gap. If the ad doesn't load, the recyclerview won't have gap, how can I do it?

Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.listEvent.ListEventFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: If the ad loads]

[image: If the ad doesnt load]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the Ad loading failed, set the Visibility to gone

```
override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
    adView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Or you can by default set the visibility to gone in the XML file. After loading the ad successfully you can make it visible.

In the XML:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

In the code:

```
adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: Hide in the XML is making sense.